# What is the max size of a smart contract on the RSK network?

Tags: java, solidity, rsk

Does RSK have a maximum size of a compiled smart contract? If so, what is the max size of the byte code that can be deployed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is, the maximum size is `24567`, which is ~24KB.

This is defined in [`Constants#getMaxContractSize()`](https://github.com/rsksmart/rskj/blob/9a56ee28c8aae31c8bda1334e44124f83d135956/rskj-core/src/main/java/org/ethereum/config/Constants.java#L175-L177)

```java
    public static int getMaxContractSize() {
        return 0x6000;
    }
```

The specific logic during a contract deployment uses this value within
[`TransactionExecutor#createContract()`](https://github.com/rsksmart/rskj/blob/9a56ee28c8aae31c8bda1334e44124f83d135956/rskj-core/src/main/java/org/ethereum/core/TransactionExecutor.java#L456-L480)

```java
    private void createContract() {
        int createdContractSize = getLength(program.getResult().getHReturn());
        long returnDataGasValue = GasCost.multiply(GasCost.CREATE_DATA, createdContractSize);
        if (mEndGas < returnDataGasValue) {
            program.setRuntimeFailure(
                    Program.ExceptionHelper.notEnoughSpendingGas(
                            program,
                            "No gas to return just created contract",
                            returnDataGasValue));
            result = program.getResult();
            result.setHReturn(EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY);
        } else if (createdContractSize > Constants.getMaxContractSize()) {
            program.setRuntimeFailure(
                    Program.ExceptionHelper.tooLargeContractSize(
                            program,
                            Constants.getMaxContractSize(),
                            createdContractSize));
            result = program.getResult();
            result.setHReturn(EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY);
        } else {
            mEndGas = GasCost.subtract(mEndGas,  returnDataGasValue);
            program.spendGas(returnDataGasValue, "CONTRACT DATA COST");
            cacheTrack.saveCode(tx.getContractAddress(), result.getHReturn());
        }
    }
```

The part of the above function relevant to your question, is that the condition
`(createdContractSize > Constants.getMaxContractSize())`
needs to be satisfied, otherwise an exception is thrown.